# Read only file system on Android

Tags: android

I recently rooted my Droid X and everything seems to be working perfectly. I made some changes to `build.prop` and when I do `adb push build.prop /system/` I get the following error: `failed to copy 'c:\build.prop' to '/system//build.prop': Read-only file system`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: have you tried `adb remount`, what do you get?

Comment: _Android is Google's software stack ... For non-developer questions, see http://android.stackexchange.com_

Comment: Please note that this question should not be confused with the case where Android **Application** code fails with a read-only file system error.  That is usually caused by trying to write a file without specifying a location, ie, trying to write to the root directory.  This question is *only* about modifying the installation of Android itself on rooted/development/engineering devices.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with an android emulator?? None of these solutions work for my emulator.

Comment: Just use `adb shell mount -o rw,remount /sys` (instead of /system). Works for me.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Got this off an Android forum where I asked the same question. Hope this helps somebody else.

On a terminal emulator on the phone:

```
mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
```

Then on the cmd prompt, do the `adb push`

Comment: `adb shell <command>` can be used from the computer (if you lack a terminal on your phone)

Comment: this comments results in ```mount: '/system' not in /proc/mounts```

Comment: @임정섭 I am also facing the same issue, did you find any solution? nothing is working for me. if I am doing adb remount, I am getting `remount of the / superblock failed: Permission denied
remount failed` and with this answer, I am getting `'/system' not in /proc/mounts`. Please help.

Comment: @HackRx I kind of gave up and found other proxy methods. Overall, what I wanted to was pushing some data to the phones and I did this by pushing to /data/local/ . Here didn't raise permission error.

Answer (score 438):

Not all phones and versions of android have things mounted the same.
Limiting options when remounting would be best.

Simply remount as rw (Read/Write):

```
# mount -o rw,remount /system
```

Once you are done making changes, remount to ro (read-only):

```
# mount -o ro,remount /system
```

Comment: You can do this on your PC too.
adb shell mount -o rw,remount /system

Comment: Use in conjunction with `adb root` or you'll get a Permission Denied when pushing the file.

Comment: mount: permission denied

Comment: @MikeHenke, it sounds like you were not root when you executed it.

Comment: @MikeHenke or you need to remember to run "su" beforehand or prefix the command with "su", to give the shell root access.

Comment: mount: Operation not permitted

Comment: If I use `adb root` I get `adbd cannot run as root in production builds`

Comment: remember that don't run this command it directly on your Linux/Mac :-)

Comment: @L'Esperanza This works fine, you don't have the privileges required to do it. You need to have super user permissions. Try doing it as root

Comment: Yes. I detected problem with android. I can't root it.

Comment: if i tried the command above as a SU" mode... but still got permission denied, what should I do then? @curtlee2002

Comment: Doesn't work for me:
`Balazss-MBP:tools varh1i$ adb shell`
       
`generic_x86_64:/ # mount -o rw,remount /system`
`'/dev/block/vda' is read-only`

Comment: It is not worked for me.It showed "mount: Read-only file system"

Comment: Since I had root anyway, I copied the file to /sdcard, then used (in my case) `mv hosts /system/etc/hosts`

Comment: "mount: '/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system'->'/system': Device or resource busy"

Comment: @Daniel you've probably solved that, but i write for general knowledge. you should use the google api devices and not google play

Comment: samsung tab a after that reboots and everything is back as it was

Comment: @BalazsVarhegyi did you try `remount /dev` ? Otherwise you are only remounting the `/system` directory

Comment: If you get an error like `mount: '/system' not in /proc/mounts`, you can try remounting the `/` directory instead of `/system` directory

Answer (score 104):

```
adb remount
```

works for me and seems to be the simplest solution.

Comment: "adb remount -- If you've gotten errors trying to push files to /system due to it being in read-only mode, adb remount will remount /system into read-write mode--- provided that the shell has the correct root permissions to do so. This replaces having to type a longer command by hand such as mount -o rw,remount /system (as root) or something." ([source](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc:_Building_Basics#ADB)). If you have any issue with root permissions, try "adb root" before.

Comment: I've got `Not running as root. Try "adb root" first.`. And then `adbd cannot run as root in production builds`.

Comment: On newer devices it looks like we also need to `$ adb disable-verity` and then reboot the device before we can run `$ adb remount`

Comment: $ adb disable-verity give : disable-verity only works for userdebug builds

Comment: it doesn't work: `Not running as root. Try "adb root" first.`. I entered `adb root` and then again `adb remount` but still the same error: `Not running as root. Try "adb root" first.`

Comment: Doing this on OnePlus Nord CE 5G seems to break mobile connection, I can no longer get texts or use data

Comment: @user924 you need to enable root access from ADB on Developer Settings (if present)

Answer (score 90):

While I know the question is about the real device, in case someone got here with a similar issue in the emulator, with whatever tools are the latest as of Feb, 2017, the emulator needs to be launched from the command line with:

```
-writable-system
```

For anything to be writable to the `/system`. Without this flag no combination of `remount` or `mount` will allow one to write to `/system`.

After the emulator is launched with that flag, a single `adb remount` after `adb root` is sufficient to get permissions to push to `/system`.

Here's an example of the command line I use to run my emulator:

```
./emulator -writable-system -avd Nexus_5_API_25 -no-snapshot-load -qemu
```

The value for the `-avd` flags comes from:

```
./emulator -list-avds
```

Comment: my command prompt becomes extremely slow until cannot continue with adb root and adb remount after launch emulator with -writable-system, anyone can help ?

Comment: Note that in some old kernel versions there is a bug in the ext4 driver that causes the remount to immediately revert to read-only.  Check dmesg for error messages like "Inode table for bg 0 marked as needing zeroing".  This is fixed by [commit 8844618](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/5012284700775a4e6e3fbe7eac4c543c4874b559)

Comment: What if I want to write to `/product` directory?

Comment: In case you are on windows, Right-click the Bluestacks icon on Desktop > Properties > Target (And add flags there)

Answer (score 29):

```
adb disable-verity
adb reboot
adb root
adb remount
```

This works for me, and is the simplest solution.

Comment: adb disable-verity -- this was the key solution in my case.

Comment: verity cannot be disabled/enabled - USER build

Comment: This is the right answer. I just had to push "adb root" as the very first command, otherwise I'm getting "Error getting verity state. Try adb root first?
Overlayfs setup failed with error Permission denied
Maybe run adb root?" on Android Emulator SDK 29.

Answer (score 28):

I think the safest way is remounting the /system as read-write, using:

```
mount -o remount,rw /system
```

and when done, remount it as read-only:

```
mount -o remount,ro /system
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your answer is technically useful, but essentially a duplicate of curtlee2002's prior answer. This might have been better as a comment on his answer saying "I agree it is safest to switch back to read-only after monkeying around in read-write mode." We have millions of questions, so there will always be another question where you are the first to come with a great solution or a fresh perspective!

Comment: this only worked for me once I removed the "," from the statement. i.e.  "" **mount -o remount rw /system**  ""

Comment: @TechnikEmpire, he does not refer to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 16):

On my Samsung galaxy mini S5570 (after got root on cellphone):

Fist, as root, I ran:

```
systemctl start adb
```

as a normal user:

```
adb shell 
su
```

Grant root permissions on touch screen

```
mount
```

list all mount points that we have and we can see, in my case, that /dev/stl12 was mounted on /system as ro (ready only), so we just need do:

```
mount -o rw,remount /dev/stl12 /system
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. For some reason I never looked at the screen on my phone to grant root permissions and was getting access denied no matter what I tried.

Comment: saying "You must specify a filesystem type with -t.", whats does this mean?

Comment: mount -o rw,remount -t ext4 /dev/block/vda /system , -t mean the type of file system in my example ext4

Answer (score 12):

Try the following on the command prompt:

```
>adb remount
>adb push framework-res_old.apk /system/framework-res.apk
```

Comment: It should be `adb root remount`

Answer (score 9):

Here is what worked for me. I was running an emulated Android 7.1.1 (Nougat) device.

On a terminal, I hit the following command. One thing to be noticed is the -writable-system flag

```
./emulator -writable-system -avd Nexus_6_API_25  -partition-size 280
```

On another tab

```
./adb shell
su
mount -o rw,remount -t ext4 /dev/block/vda /system
```

All the changes that you do on the /system contents will survive a restart.

Comment: `mount: '/system' not in /proc/mounts`

Answer (score 8):

I checked with emulator and following worked.

1. adb reboot
2. adb root && adb remount && adb push ~/Desktop/hosts /system/etc/hosts

As mentioned above as well, execute second step in single shot.

Comment: I had one console open for pushing and one for remounting.
Remount, switch to the other terminal where you have the push line ready to submit, and submit it. That's it.

Answer (score 3):

Open terminal emulator on the phone:
then

```
adb shell
```

after that daemon is started

```
su
mount -o rw,remount /mnt/sdcard
```

then the read only is converted into the read-Write.

Answer (score 2):

```
mount -o rw,remount /dev/stl12 /system
```

works for me

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you get the error because the destination location in phone are not exist. For example, some android phone external storage location is `/storage/emulated/legacy` instead of `/storage/emulated/0`.

Answer (score 2):

```
This worked for me

#Mount as ReadOnly

su -c "mount -o rw,remount /system"
# Change Permission for file
su -c "chmod 777 /system/build.prop" 
#Edit the file to add the property
su -c "busybox vi /system/build.prop"
# Add now
service.adb.tcp.port=5678

# Reset old permissions
su -c "chmod 644 /system/build.prop"

# Mount as readonly again once done
su -c "mount -o ro,remount /system"
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this article from google, and thought I'd add the steps necessary on a Sony Xperia Z (4.2.2).

The Sony has a watchdog process which detects when you've changed ro to rw on / and /system (these are the only ones I was trying to modify) and possibly others.

The following was what I ran to perform the changes I was trying to achieve.  I pasted these into a window, because removing the execute bit from /sbin/ric needs to be done quickly in order to stop it restarting itself.  (I tried `stop ric`; this doesn't work - although it worked on a previous version of android on the phone).

```
pkill -9 ric; mount -o rw,remount -t rootfs /
chmod 640 /sbin/ric
mount -o rw,remount /system
```

I modified the hosts file here, so this is the place you make the changes you need to the filesystem.  To leave things the way we found them, do this:

```
mount -o ro,remount /system
chmod 750 /sbin/ric
mount -o ro,remount -t rootfs /
```

At which point ric should automatically restart.  (It restarted for me automatically.)

Answer (score 1):

Adding a little bit more to Jan Bergström's answer: Because Android is a Linux based system, and the path in Linux contains forward slashes(../), while using push command, use "/" to define destination path in the Android device.

For Example, the command goes: adb push C:\Users\admin\Desktop\1.JPG sdcard/pictures/

Notice that here, back slashes are used to define source path of the file to be pushed from windows PC and forward slashes are used to define destination path because Android is a Linux based system. You don't have to act as a root to use this command and also, it works perfectly fine on production devices.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, **Sérgio**, for "mount" command without parameters idea.
I'd need to made `adb push` into `/data/data/com.my.app/lib` for some test issue, and get "Read-only filesystem" message.

ls command shows me:

`root@android:/ # ls -l /data/data/com.my.app/

drwxrwx--x u0_a98   u0_a98            2016-05-06 09:16 cache
drwxrwx--x u0_a98   u0_a98            2016-05-06 09:04 files
lrwxrwxrwx system   system            2016-05-06 11:43 lib -> /mnt/asec/com.my.app-1/lib`

So, it's understood, that "lib" directory is separated from other application directories.

Command
`mount -o rw,remount /mnt/asec`
didn't resolve "r/o fs" issue, it wants device parameter before directory parameter.

"df" command didn't help also, but shows that my `/mnt/asec/com.my.app-1` directory is at the separate mount point.

Then I looks by `mount` and voila!

`root@android:/ # mount
.........
/dev/block/dm-4 /mnt/asec/com.my.app-1 ext4 ro,dirsync,relatime 0 0`

Next steps are already described upwards: remount to RW, push and remount back to RO.

Answer (score 1):

it sames that must extract and repack initrc.img and edit `init` file with the code of mount /system

Comment: btw. you must start avd with -writeable-system options

Answer (score 0):

### Copy files to the SD-card?

Well, I assume you like to copy data to the Sd-card from the developers computer? You might have rooted the devise and made the area you address available?) I had about the same problem to upload data files for my application(Android Studio 1.3.2 in Win7), but.

- First the adb command-shell has to be found in th path: 
  PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools (the folder AppData is hidden, so you have to set the folder setup not hiding concealed files and folder to find it, Path works regardless)
- You have to spell the folder path right or you get a read-only error message, most likely it must start with /sdcard or it is read only area. As soon as I did no problem pushing the file to the emulator.

So for instance the the adb command can look like this:

adb push C:\testdata\t.txt /sdcard/download/t.txt

Answer (score 0):

If there's a failure in copying the read-only file you can try locating the original file in the root directory and modify it with a root text editor (preferably) RB text editor, it comes with ROM Toolbox app.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in a Terminal Emulator as root:

```
restorecon -v -R /data/media
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using the command adb push `~/Desktop/file.txt ~/sdcard/`

I changed it to `~/Desktop/file.txt /sdcard/` and then it worked.

Make sure to disconnect and reconnect the phone.

Comment: The author of this question asks about remounting the /system as read-write, your answer is kinda off topic

Answer (score -2):

As [chen-xing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/864532/chen-xing) mentioned the simplest way is:

```
adb reboot
```

But for me I had to change my settings first:

*Settings → Developer options → Root access*

Make sure ADB has Root access:

[image]

Comment: I've seen this alot, but I don't have this option on ANY of my devices. Emulator or otherwise.