# Unauthorize and App from AccountManager Credential Access

Tags: android, accountmanager

I have an app that I'm developing that uses AccountManager to get credentials for a Google account that is subsequently used for getting a cookie from AppEngine.  I've noticed that I find bugs when I send the app to testers because they get prompted to authorize the account.  I need to do a bunch of testing and am looking for a way to "unauthorize" an app from a particular credential so I can do my testing on the next install.  I can't find anything in settings where I can remove the authorization to an account from an app.  Do you know of a way to do this?

Thank you,
Stateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least as of 2.3, there is no API for this. IIRC, if you install the application, the authorization entry will be removed from the database, so a re-install should work.

Comment: In order to test the registration activity I have to uninstall; this activity doesn't show once the device is successfully registered to the app at AppEngine.  Uninstall has worked a couple times (out of probably 100 so far) but it's not consistent.  So far the only way to consistently get it to request authorization for the account is to restore the phone to factory defaults which takes a while each time.

Comment: Uninstalling and re-installing doesn't work for me (Galaxy S III, 4.0.3). It's still kept somwhere. This might work though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852256/how-do-you-force-accountmanager-to-show-the-access-request-screen-after-a-user

Comment: Removing and re-adding the Goolge account should always work, but that may not doable if you that is the primary Google account on the device.

Comment: BTW, newer versions of Google Login Service don't store this in the grants table, but in the `extras` one, so you might want to clear that too.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that uninstalling is most of the time not enough. You need to uninstall and restart the phone right afterwards. At least this works for me

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove from this page:

https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens?hl=it