# Revoke access from Android app using Google Drive SDK v2

Tags: android, google-drive-api

How to revoke the authorization and not the token using the Google Drive SDK v2 for Android ?

Comment: Have you solved the problem?
I am interested to know the solution too.

Answer (score 1):

See this question: [Where to revoke Google API permissions granted on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561525/where-to-revoke-google-api-permissions-granted-on-android)

See the solution from "AndroidDev", I am using his solution and it is working for me.

Answer (score -2):

Revoking the token and the authorization are the same thing. Go here and revoke it:

https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens