# sqlite3 on Android fails with: syntax error: unexpected "("

Tags: android, sqlite

I pushed sqlite3 (from my Android SDK tools folder) to my rooted device (**Galaxy S III, 4.0.3**), since it wasn't on there.

But executing any query fails with an error, even just calling '`sqlite3`' alone.

via `adb shell`:

```
~ # sqlite3
/system/xbin/sqlite3: line 1: syntax error: unexpected "("

~ # sqlite3 /data/system/accounts.db "delete from grants;"
/system/xbin/sqlite3: line 1: syntax error: unexpected "("
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

See if putting quotes around sqlite3 on the command line works: `~ # "sqlite3"`

Comment: The only explanation I've gotten is some kind of compatibility issue between 32 bit and 64 bit systems

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I was on the wrong command line. It's not working on Android. I was still on my Mac console accidentially, not on Android. On Android, it still doesn't work, same error.

Answer (score 0):

When starting, `sqlite3` executes the file `~/.sqliterc`.
Check whether it exists, and what it contains.

But in this case, it would output a message `-- Loading resources from .../.sqliterc`, so this is not what happens here.

Comment: I only pushed sqlite3 from my pc to the device, nothing else. Sqlite wasn't on there before, just fyi. I don't see any .sqliterc anywhere. Where is ~ supposed to reference to? I tried both as regular user and su. "ls ~" would return "ls: ~: No such file or directory" on the device.

Comment: `~` is the home directory of the current user.

Comment: Ok, ~ is only available as root user / su, not as regular user. Anyhow, .sqliterc does not exist in there (/data/.sqliterc), where /data/ is the root's home dir