# Trouble having when pushing files to DDMS?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, adb

I'm trying to push one mp3 file to (Emulator) the location `/system/media/audio/ui` using command `adb push` But, i'm having

```
E:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb push song.mp3 /system/media/audio/ui
failed to copy 'song.mp3' to '/system/media/audio/ui/song.mp3': Read-only file system
```

this error. How can i change the Permission or how to push the files to this location. Any idea?

Comment: try this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066030/read-only-file-system-on-android

Comment: @suri sahani : Give this as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a really good reason not to, you should stay in the `/sdcard/` folder. Except for `/sdcard/`, most of the file system is read-only for a normal user.

It is possible, but not recommended, to "root" the phone. After which you would have full access to the whole system. Attempting this on a real phone, could break the phone, or invalidate your warranty.

If you wish to get root-privileges on the emulator, you can look at the accepted answer to this question: [how to root/getroot access on android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095234/how-to-root-getroot-access-on-android-emulator/6084432#6084432)

Answer (score 0):

That means your emulator does not support the sdcard. So create the emulator with sdcard option. see the bello image...

[image]