# Dealing with Read-only file system while trying to write to SD-card

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I try to write some data to SD-card but as you can see I have used TOAST and I get this msg when I press addbtn :
**"Read only file system"**
and it's obvious that it doesn't write to sd-card
so how should I solve this?
thanks in advance
here's the code I used:

```
case R.id.donebtn:
    if (subject.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, emptysbj.class));
    }
    else {
        String s = subject.getText().toString();
        String n = note.getText().toString();
        try {
            File mydir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + "myTasks" + File.separator + s);
        mydir.mkdirs();
        File myFile = new File(s);
        myFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter =
                new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        myOutWriter.append(n);
        myOutWriter.close();
        fOut.close();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "Done writing to SD :" + s,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
finish();
break;
```

here's my LogCat stack:

```
> 10-15 19:36:27.195: I/[POST_RESELECT](8750): [spanChange] (o,
> oldStart, newStart, oldEnd,
> newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$START@401041e0,-1,0,-1,0) 10-15
> 19:36:27.195: I/[POST_RESELECT](8750): [spanChange] (o, oldStart,
> newStart, oldEnd,
> newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$END@401402b8,-1,0,-1,0) 10-15
> 19:36:27.195: I/[POST_RESELECT](8750): [spanChange] (o, oldStart,
> newStart, oldEnd,
> newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$START@401041e0,-1,0,-1,0) 10-15
> 19:36:27.195: I/[POST_RESELECT](8750): [spanChange] (o, oldStart,
> newStart, oldEnd,
> newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$END@401402b8,-1,0,-1,0) 10-15
> 19:36:27.205: I/[POST_RESELECT](8750): [spanChange] (o, oldStart,
> newStart, oldEnd,
> newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$START@401041e0,-1,0,-1,0) 10-15
> 19:36:27.205: I/[POST_RESELECT](8750): [spanChange] (o, oldStart,
> newStart, oldEnd,
> newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$END@401402b8,-1,0,-1,0) 10-15
> 19:36:29.067: I/[POST_RESELECT](8750):
> [sendCursorChangeNotificationToIME] ENTER... 10-15 19:36:29.067:
> I/[POST_RESELECT](8750): NOW IS XXX NOT COMPOSING..... 10-15
> 19:36:29.067: I/[POST_RESELECT](8750): [getWordOnCursor] cursor_pos=0
> 10-15 19:36:29.067: I/[POST_RESELECT](8750):
> [sendCursorChangeNotificationToIME] TAP..... 10-15 19:36:29.067:
> I/[POST_RESELECT](8750):
> [sendCursorChangeNotificationToIME](content,cursor_start,tap)=(,0,false)
> 10-15 19:36:29.617: I/[POST_RESELECT](8750): [handleTextChanged]
> (start,before,after)=(0,0,1) 10-15 19:36:29.817:
> I/[POST_RESELECT](8750): [handleTextChanged]
> (start,before,after)=(1,0,1) 10-15 19:36:29.998:
> I/[POST_RESELECT](8750): [handleTextChanged]
> (start,before,after)=(2,0,1) 10-15 19:36:31.209: E/No such file or
> directory(8750): Erfan
```

Comment: message of the exception?

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066030/read-only-file-system-on-android

Comment: @Seraphim just highlighted the message of exception, look at my edited question again please

Comment: I answered your question try it. Good luck!

Comment: @Seraphim I am inside windows and I didn't get what that forum was mentioning, would u guide me to a simple way so that I can write in sd-card from within my app?

Comment: Are you using a standard Android s.o.?

Comment: Inside Windows? With the emulator?

Comment: I'm using my phone to test it, it's wildfire-s

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
 File mydir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +File.separator+
                            "myTasks"+File.separator+s);
```

to:

```
 File mydir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myTasks");
```

Then, change:

```
 File myFile = new File(s);
```

to:

```
 File myFile = new File(mydir, s);
```

Comment: didn't solve my problem, this time I get this msg : No such file or directory(I guess that's because I can't write to mem and it's read-only

Comment: @user2541758: Paste your entire stack trace into your question.

Comment: @user2541758: That is not a stack trace.

Comment: how should i get stack trace then?sorry I'm newbie

Comment: @user2541758: It looks like you are not actually logging it. You are catching the `Exception` and then just displaying a `Toast`. Use `Log.e()` to log the `Exception` and its stack trace to LogCat.

Comment: I just used it, you can see  it now

Comment: @user2541758: In the future, use the three-parameter version of `Log.e()`, that takes your `Exception` as the third parameter, to generate an actual stack trace. Your problem is that you are trying to open a file named simply `"Erfan"`, which will not work, as it is not a fully-qualified path. If you follow the instructions in my answer, you will get a fully-qualified path.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the code you have is **trying to write inside** `/` which is **read only**. If you want to store the file inside SD card, you have to change to :

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(root, "myTasks" + File.separator + s);
```