# EROFS error while creating file

Tags: java, android, file

I'm using this code to create a file but I'm getting this error:

```
java.io.IOEx: open failed: EROFS (Read only file system)
```

The system is mounted as rw and the app has SU permissions.

```
File f = new File(Environment.getRootDirectory().getPath().toString(), "/etc/init.d/script");
if (!f.exists()) {
    try {
        mountSystemRW();
        f.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? [If you want your app to start at boot there are better ways](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6391902/243712).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read only file system on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066030/read-only-file-system-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

The Android root filesystem is always mounted readonly because it's meant to contain only the system image.

If you have rooted your device you can run

```
# mount -o rw,remount /
```

Comment: I mount system by this, it is okay?  "mount -o rw,remount /system"

Comment: Actually `/` is different to `/system`. But, again, why are you trying to do this? The root filesystem is created at startup so putting a service file there won't help much.

Comment: I wanna create scripts using an app, so I need to create a file into "/system/etc/init.d", but I can't as you can see

Answer (score 0):

Regardless if the filesystem in question mounted read-only as normal, or has been changed to read-write, an **application process** is still never able to write to a file for which it lacks access rights.

Application code such as your java excerpt cannot run as root, period.  Only helper processes can.