# How to add android.hardware.usb.host.xml inside /system/etc/permissions in android

Tags: android, permissions, adb, root

I did a backup restore on my phone `Cherry Mobile Infinix Pure XL (Model: X210)` and I found out that `USB-OTG` is not working. So I take a look on the `permissions` folder (reference: [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oaXYMx8-SZ4)) and noticed that `android.hardware.usb.host.xml` is missing. I did a lot of research on how to add this file in that directory but nothing works.

I just did this
https://superuser.com/questions/126073/chmod-to-allow-read-and-write-permissions-for-directory

this
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1389728

and this
[Read only file system on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066030/read-only-file-system-on-android)

but I always end up having this error `Device not found`.
My phone is already rooted using `iRoot`. I use `SuperSU` for granting permissions.

**Edit**
I've made it.... Using `Android Commander` and http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1687590
By these things I was able to copy and paste the xml file. YET!!! `USB-OTG` doesn't work still... I hate it!!!

**Edit 2**

Woaaaahh!!! It is solved!!
Here is what I did:

1. Completely unroot the device
2. After unrooting, do a hard reset using the recovery mode
3. Then restore backup data again

So there could be a problem when you root the device and forgot to un-root it before restoring backup data. Happy now.. :)

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this on my Samsung S9+ as well, it is rooted and stumbled across this genius site [rfexplorer.com/usb-host-mode/](https://rfexplorer.com/usb-host-mode/) which explains in details that OTG is loaded during boot and if the [.xml-file](http://nutsaboutnets-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/install-adb.zip) is not present, OTG will not work.

The easiest method I found to is to simply download the [.xml](http://nutsaboutnets-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/install-adb.zip) and paste it to /system/etc/permissions with a root file explorer, reboot and bam, it worked. You can use ADB if you like and, which is described in detail in the link.

Comment: [link](https://rfexplorer.com/usb-host-mode/) is dead. [see web archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20230000000000*/https://rfexplorer.com/usb-host-mode/)