# adb: error: failed to copy ....... couldn't create file: Read-only file system

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, file-permissions

```
$ adb shell
# mkdir data/local/tmp/testjars
# exit
```

That works fine and gives no errors, but when I do:

```
$ adb push <project_root_folder>/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk data/local/tmp/testjar/load.apk
```

I get the error:

```
adb: error: failed to copy 'F:\dexclassloader\PluginSample\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk' to 'data\local\tmp\testjar\load.apk': couldn't create file: Read-only file system
```

What am I missing? How can I fix this?

---

Im deploying my app on **Virtual devices** (**Nexus 5**).

> **Android Studio 2.2.3**
>   Build #AI-145.3537739, built on December 2, 2016
>   JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b03 amd64
>   JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
>
> **Windows 10**

Comment: I don't know if AVDs have a /sdcard but if they have you can try to push to /sdcard and then cp from /sdcard to /data/..

Comment: @Program-Me-Rev - Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read only file system on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066030/read-only-file-system-on-android)