# "adb root" command returns "adbd cannot run as root in production builds" even on an emulator?

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to run the `adb root` command on an emulator; this is the only device I have attached:

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
```

However, I'm getting the following error message:

```
$ adb root
adbd cannot run as root in production builds
```

I've tried following this answer, [adb shell su works but adb root does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477424/adb-shell-su-works-but-adb-root-does-not), to solve my problem:

> By design adb root command works in development builds only (i.e. eng and userdebug which have ro.debuggable=1 by default). Alternatively you could use modified adbd binary (which does not check for ro.debuggable)

It is not clear to me, however, how I can change the build into a development build instead of a production one?

**Update**
I've found some additional instructions which lead me to believe that for this to work, you need to make your emulator a 'writable system' (cf. [How to make system partition in AVD in emulator writable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42647209/how-to-make-system-partition-in-avd-in-emulator-writable)). However, if I try

```
$ emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_28 -writable-system
emulator: WARNING: System image is writable
emulator: ERROR: Running multiple emulators with the same AVD is an experimental feature.
Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature.
```

I'm not really sure how to parse this error message; does this mean that the system image is already writable?

Comment: Can you check if this is related:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43923996/adb-root-is-not-working-on-emulator-cannot-run-as-root-in-production-builds

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I checked some emulator provided by Google.
They are all user binary, not engineer binary.
You can check it yourself by using "adb shell" command.
If command line starts with "#", it's engineer build. If it starts with "$", it's user build. For example:

- jackpot2lte:/ # => engineer build
- jackpot2lte:/ $ => user build

Only engineer build can give you root permission. You can not change user build to engineer build but you can 'root' it.
Please check ["How to get root access on Android emulator?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095234/how-to-get-root-access-on-android-emulator) for more information.

Comment: Indeed a I see a `$` in the `adb shell` indicating that it's a user build. However, from the comment above it seems there is also a `userdebug` build?

Comment: Bad answer. As the other answer explains, it's only the 'Play Store' images have root shell disabled.

Answer (score 6):

Pick an emulator system image that is NOT labelled "Google Play".

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/45668555.

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be marked as such. The non-play store builds give you a root shell without needing any jailbreak.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating From Xanhacks answer above

[image: Android Studio Device manager]

If using VSCode ensure you can add rooted virtual device in Android Studio (its sharable to VSCode)

Then search google and download "platform-tools for adb"  on Windows

Example interaction with device Using VSCode below...(i've already installed sqlite on virtual device)

[image: VSCode Terminal]