# Problem with adb push command read-only file system

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to copy a file via cmd Windows 7 to a Samsung Tablet but I get the following message:

```
remote could not create the file.Read-only system.
```

Why does it happen? How can I remove it? I execute the command adb list devices and my tablet appears normally, but I cannot copy the file adb push filename `/Sdcard/Android/etc`.

Comment: You have to follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066030/read-only-file-system-on-android