# How to remount the read-only system folder in android avd virtual device

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I needed to place some files in system/etc and no method of remounting as read-write was allowing me to write into the read-only system folder. It took me forever to find a solution so just wanted to place this as a separate question so that people don't have to go through that exercise. 
The answer was found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42280124/10844761
many thanks to ishamael

and here's the summary:

you need to open the emulator with -writable-system

go to /path/to/andorid/sdk/emulator and run 
./emulator -writable-system avd name-of-your-device-emulator

if you don't know the name of your device emulator run 
./emulator -list-avds

now once the emulator starts up run 
adb root
adb remount

now you can write to system folder :)