# ADB push error: failed to copy: Not a directory

Tags: android, file, adb, push, hosts

So I'm just trying to modify the hosts file on a family members phone.  I've put the phone in debug mode and pulled the hosts file, edited it, but when I try to push it I get the message, "adb: error: failed to copy 'D:/hosts\hosts' to '/system/etc/hosts/hosts': remote couldn't create file: Not a directory"

Here's the commands I've used:

```
adb pull /system/etc/hosts D:\hosts
/system/etc/hosts: 1 file pulled. 0.0 MB/s (56 bytes in 0.003s)

adb push D:\hosts /system/etc/
adb: error: failed to copy 'D:\hosts\hosts' to '/system/etc/hosts/hosts': remote couldn't create file: Not a directory
```

This is my first time using android debugging/adb and nothing else I've read helped.  Thanks in advance.

EDIT: So I've made a little progress.  I realized that the hosts file is not in a hosts directory, so I changed it to `adb push D:\hosts /system/etc` which still didn't work, but `adb push D:\hosts\hosts /system/etc` gave me the response `adb: error: failed to copy 'D:\hosts\hosts' to '/system/etc/hosts': remote couldn't create file: Read-only file system`  So it looks like my problem is now in `adb shell chmod`

EDIT2: So after some more research I came across this [Read only file system on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066030/read-only-file-system-on-android/42280124).  When trying `mount -o rw,remount /system` I get `mount: '/dev/block/dm-0' not user mountable in fstab`.  In the mounts file /dev/block/dm-0 is on /system.  The new problem is fstab is not located in /etc

EDIT3: It looks like my big problem is I have to root the phone I think.  I don't have su or sudo to do the remount.  Seeing as it's not mine, I don't want to root the phone.